# location manager was created on a dispatch queue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

what does this message mean?

NOTICE,A location manager (0xe86bdf0) was created on a dispatch queue executing on a thread other than the main thread.  It is the developer's responsibility to ensure that there is a run loop running on the thread on which the location manager object is allocated.  In particular, creating location managers in arbitrary dispatch queues (not attached to the main queue) is not supported and will result in callbacks not being received.

Comment: Thanks to the answers below. just had to move everything to the AppDelegate class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must create the CLLocationManager on a thread with an active run loop, such as the main thread. You should not create it on a background thread. See [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) for more information:

> (Configuration of your location manager object must always occur on a thread with an active run loop, such as your application’s main thread.)

If you're interested in what exactly a run loop is, see [Run Loops](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) for further information.

Comment: As far as you know, this issue is related only to the GPS? Because with CMMotionManager (accelerometer, for instance) I don't see this issue.

Answer (score 6):

With Swift 3, the following will ensure your function runs on main thread:

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation{"your location manager init code"}
```

Comment: OperationQueue is powerful feature .
it worked for me.

Comment: The same is available for ObjC: `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{}]`

Answer (score 2):

It means that if you created a location manager in another thread besides the "Main" thread (i.e., the thread where all the UI code for you app executes), you need to make sure to always call it (i.e., the location manager) from the thread that created it.

To debug the problem in your code, you might want to wrap the creation of (and the calls to )the location manager inside a dispatch queue for the main thread thusly:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
});
```

and:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
});
```

Or something like that to see if the error message goes away.

Comment: for some reason this solution blocks my main thread when I trying to use it.

Comment: This was a debugging solution--a way to figure out what is going on by forcing a run on the main queue. I think you might have a backward understanding of the suggestion.