# Location Manager not updating location in swift. AlertView disappears

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I want to get location inside a custom delegate in swift. Note that this worked perfectly 2 hours ago. The major problem is that the Location authorization alertView disappears by its own before I get to Allow it. So i tried to go within settings and allow it but it does not work. Why is the alertView disappearing by it self and why even though I allowed it through the settings I still cannot get an update? I added the correct key in the plist and also added the delegate and CoreLocation framework in the file. Also note that the didFail is not called at any point. Any advise would be appreciated

```
func getLocation(){
    println("called")
    let locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    println(status.rawValue)

    if(status != CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        println("called2")
    }else{
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        println("allowed and updating")
    }




}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("updating")

    var locationArray = locations as NSArray
    var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as CLLocation

    println(locationObj)

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error)
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        var shouldIAllow = false
        println(status)
        switch status {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
            println("Restricted Access to location")
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            println("User denied access to location")
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            println("Status not determined")
        default:
            println("Allowed to location Access")
            shouldIAllow = true
        }

        if (shouldIAllow == true) {
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            println("Denied access: \(status)")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a property from `locationManager` , because this way it is destroyed after you run your method. And don't forget to setup its delegate for example in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Well I got it to work following your instructions but also moving it away from my custom delegate which raises my question: Does locationManager updatingLocations needs to be on the main thread? I mean it worked perfectly like 3 hours ago through a custom delegate..

Comment: @snksnk I'm not sure what do you mean by "moving it away from my custom delegate". And what do you mean by custom delegate? And answering your question: updateingLocations is fired on the main thread, so it is on the main thread.

Comment: I created a delegate which is called through the mainViewController and through that delegate I want to update Location

Comment: You mean locationManager by delegate?

Comment: According to this http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/cllocationmanager-and-thread-safety/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707038/location-manager-was-created-on-a-dispatch-queue CllocationManager has to be on the main thread

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think he's wrong, when he write that locationManager has to be created on the main thread. I would say that the only important thing is to call the startUpdatingLocation on the main thread.