# Access user current location in custom Sirikit intends, iOS, swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios12, sirikit

I created a custom Sirikit intent, in IntentHandler class I can not find the location of user where location privacy is set by default 'Always'.
please look at the code.

```
    import Foundation
import CoreData
import CoreLocation
class PhotoOfTheDayIntentHandler: NSObject, PhotoOfTheDayIntentHandling {
let context = CoreDataStorage.mainQueueContext()
var counter : DistanceEntity?
var locationManger = CLLocationManager()
    func confirm(intent: PhotoOfTheDayIntent, completion: @escaping (PhotoOfTheDayIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        completion(PhotoOfTheDayIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: nil))
}

func handle(intent: PhotoOfTheDayIntent, completion: @escaping (PhotoOfTheDayIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    self.context.performAndWait{ () -> Void in
        let counter = NSManagedObject.findAllForEntity("DistanceEntity", context: self.context)
        if (counter?.last != nil) {
            self.counter = (counter!.last as! DistanceEntity)
                let currentLocation: CLLocation = locationManger.location!
                let greenLocation = CLLocation(latitude:self.counter!.latitude, longitude: self.counter!.longitude)
                let distanceInMeters = currentLocation.distance(from: greenLocation) // result is in meters
                debugPrint("distanceInMeters",distanceInMeters)
                completion(PhotoOfTheDayIntentResponse.success(photoTitle: "\(distanceInMeters) Meter"))
            completion(PhotoOfTheDayIntentResponse.success(photoTitle: "\(self.counter!.distance) Meter"))
        }
    }
}
}
```

if I comment the location manager it crash.

Comment: Did you find a solution to get user location in intent handler?

Comment: yes, I found the solution.

Comment: Can you post the solution here? I have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: @Tongo I did add an answer below that may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585774/1322262

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: Create `CLLocationManager` in the main thread and it should work

---

If you open the Console.app on your mac and monitoring the device you are running the Siri Intent on you will probably se a message similar to this:

> A location manager (0xe86bdf0) was created on a dispatch queue executing on a thread other than the main thread.

(Just like in this question: [location manager was created on a dispatch queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707038/location-manager-was-created-on-a-dispatch-queue).)

The problem is that core location must be created in a run loop that is attached to the main loop. Easiest solution is to create the `CLLocationManager` in the main loop.

Here is an example intent handler that uses location.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class ExampleIntentHandler: NSObject, ExampleIntentIntentHandling, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    var onDidChangeAuthorization: ((ExampleIntentResponse) -> Void)?
    var onDidUpdateLocations: ((ExampleIntentResponse) -> Void)?

    func confirm(intent: CurrentSpeedIntent, completion: @escaping (CurrentSpeedIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.onDidChangeAuthorization = completion
            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.locationManager?.delegate = self
            self.locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func handle(intent: CurrentSpeedIntent, completion: @escaping (CurrentSpeedIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.onDidUpdateLocations = completion
            self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            self.locationManager?.delegate = self
            self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            let response = ExampleIntentResponse(code: .ready, userActivity: nil)
            onDidChangeAuthorization?(response)
        default:
            let response = ExampleIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil)
            onDidChangeAuthorization?(response)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        // Do something with the `location` but note that this
        // method could be called multiple times by iOS. So if
        // you do more that just responding, like fetching a
        // photo, or manipulate something in your database you
        // will probably set some kind of variable here and 
        // stop if that is already set.
        // 
        // Example:
        //     guard intentHandled == false else { return }
        //     intentHandled = true
        // 
        // The `intentHandled` must of course be a instance variable

        // Don't forget to respond!
        let response = ExampleIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil)
        self.onDidUpdateLocations?(response)
    }
}
```

This will also execute only when there actually is a location. I can see that you are force unwrapping your location which is a bad practice because it may be nil and then your intent will just crash. Here we will instead do what we need when we have the location.

Request to use location must also be made in the app first if that is not done yet.